# UX Registration unhappy path

Tags: user-behavior, design, notification

Running through an issue with unhappy customers not completing registration needed for payment to be processed. We badge the nav bar for the user to notice that actions are needed to complete the registration.

"about 5% of the users don't notice that and end up without completing the registration and having their money on hold"

To solve this I'm assuming the issue might be with our nav bar design and the way we badge it. I'm attaching an image of the nav bar + the settings screen.

- What are your thoughts on the "more" icon design? could it be the issue that when its badged it doesn't clearly show?
- Could it be the settings screen text alignment and spacing be the issue? so if we increase the margins between the items would give more attention if we badge and of the items?

> [image: Nav bar]
>
> [image: "More/settings" screen]

Answer (score 1):

The "more" icon is OK, IMO, but there's a bit of context missing here. Why are users allowed to proceeed without completing registration? How is it possible one gets money on hold without completing the registration.

For now I'll assume it's about money waiting to be collected. Without more context I'd classify the missing information as critical and there's nothing else more critical to be done. In this case a simple badge will be easily missed. Especially in the case of certain color blind users. Many will miss the difference between red and green, so your color scheme fails there.

I would suggest showing an alert explaining the problem and why action is required when the user opens the app and wouldn't allow the user to to any other action until the required information is entered.

Comment: In some cases, after completing the registration we ask for additional information for some users to authorize payments that clients pay them. So the money stays on hold without them knowing that they're on hold because their profile needs to be updated. This is the case for about 5% of the users, It could be from the color scheme you're right